# Android development best practices

Tags: android, layout, controls

I'm new to Android development and I have a best practices question regarding layouts on orientation change.

My question is in regards to handling layout properties when the user changes the orientation of the device.

If, for the purpose of an app, it is necessary for controls to be repositioned on the layout when the orientation is changed, should a new layout be created for that specific orientation? Or should every effort be made to reposition controls on a single layout programmatically?

Thank you for you input.

Answer (score 3):

I'll go ahead and disagree with thinksteep here :) I think a new layout is indeed the best option *if* you need to go beyond a simple size change (like moving views in relation to each other).

The Android API is designed to handle that automatically - you can have a directory called `layout-land` and `layout-port` with separate layouts for landscape and portrait respectively, and the system will use whichever is the most appropriate.

Note that you should avoid having separate layouts if you can - it's twice as much work for you to maintain and test them. Usually, using clever weights and proper RelativeLayouts can make a layout work with any resolution.

But in some cases, you really want to rearrange a layout entirely based on the orientation. As a random example, look at the current version of Google Music. In portrait, the majority of the screen is the cover art, with some information at the bottom. In landscape, the left half is the cover art, the right half is information.

I'll also close with a link to the Android docs - [check this out](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It's more about multiple screen sizes, but it does cover landscape/portrait as well.

Comment: I agree with EboMike. Also look into using fragments. You can reuse the same sub views in both orientations. Take for example the main window in the gmail app. To use fragments before Honeycomb you need the Android Compatibility Package: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Comment: Good point. Fragments are nearly essential at this point. There's a compatibility pack that only requires API level 4, so your app will still work on pretty much all devices.

Answer (score 1):

I think new layout is not best option, your program should reposition controls in best possible way. I would suggest reading these [links](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html).